# Email Notification For subscription URL not working from the newsletter

Tags: 2011, outbound-email, audience-manager

Tridion Version : Tridion 2011 SP1

When user click on the link to unsubscribe the email notification is not sent 
To unsubscribe from promotional emails please.
We get the following Error :  No contact record found for management side contact id: 5104803
URL that we add to the user is the following 
http://www.website.com/subscribe1.aspx?p=$Lncd6uWKO5DGCM006-YQJKplE1gGm-1H3kc-7ajWgFt$

Step 1) we create  user list on CSV file and import the contacts the the address book.

Step 2) we create a mailing list and distribution list

Step 3) we sent the news letter email to the contacts which is part of the address book.

Step 4) user successfully receive the newsletter , but when they try to access the unsubscription http://www.website.com/subscribe1.aspx?p=$Lncd6uWKO5DGCM006-YQJKplE1gGm-1H3kc-7ajWgFt$

we get following Error 
No contact record found for management side contact id: 5104803

we noticed that the contact ID is there on the tridion_cm_email , but we don't see the contact ID on Subscription_Management DB.
Please let me know how we can fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is unrelated to the sending of notification e-mails, but rather that your synchronization isn't working - or at least that it isn't done synchronizing by the time you send our your Mailings.

The error, and your own findings, clearly show that the Contact isn't present in the subscription management database. Since you imported them on the CM side, the synchronization process will be creating them on the CD side automatically. Provided that you have set up the Address Books to be synchronized, the service is running, everything is configured correctly, etc.

Assuming that you have previously set up synchronization [according to the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-94E41980-A2DB-4740-BB14-A9EB287D73B5), here are some things to double-check:

1. The synchronization service is running.
2. You have at least one Synchronization Target corresponding to the website that you are directing people to, and the target has not been disabled. Visiting the URLs entered on the Synchronization Target in your browser does not give errors.
3. The Address Book containing the Contacts you are e-mailing has been selected on at least one Publication and the 'Synchronize' checkbox has been checked for it.
4. The table structure of your subscription database (particularly the CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS table) matches the same table in the Audience Manager database (e.g. Tridion_cm_email)

If the above doesn't show any issues, you'll need to dig into the Event Log and log files created by the Synchronization service. It will have some clues as to how often you are synchronizing and any errors that are occurring.

Synchronization isn't instant. Exactly how long it takes depends on a lot of variables, including your configuration settings. So make sure you don't try to send Mailings immediately after importing those Contacts. You'll need to wait for synchronization to be complete. Unfortunately, there isn't any indication in the UI for when the synchronization is complete - so the average time frame is something you will have to learn by observing synchronization in your own environment.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for  your detail response. I will review and update with my findings.

Comment: Stored procedure failed: SP_FETCH_SYNCH_BATCH
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: So it's timing out when trying to figure out which Contacts to synchronize. It's possible that there's a lot of data to retrieve and it's not able to do so in the time frame specified by the default configuration settings. Maybe your database needs some maintenance love? As a workaround you can try to increase the database timeout settings in OutboundEmail.xml and see if it manages to sync then.

Comment: We have many address book and many contacts. So we disabled the address book . We created a new address booked and associted it with the existing publication and added one new contact with identification_key and identification_source same as address book name in this case synctest. We saw the conatct was added to tridion_cm_email but we restated the sync service running on CM side and we restarted the contact synchorization running the CD side. We don't see any time out error , no errors on event viewer on CM side and we  enabled logs for sync on CD no errors. No entry on subscribe DB.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to check the 'Synchronize' checkbox when you added it to the Publication. Either that or the Synchronization Target is disabled.

Comment: Peter my publication is still pointing to LIVE synchorization target and i made sure i un check the check bok for all the address and select only for testsync that i added new. Thanks for your reponse. I will add aome comments when i find anything more on this issue.